# Scoped enumerations

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I'm working on a simple Breakout clone to practice my fledgeling C++ skills. The game's resources are subclassed from a class called 'Resource', which will consist of an ID used to identify the type of resource and a handful of virtual functions. So far the class looks like this:

```
class Resource {
private:
    int _id;
protected:
    enum ResourceType {
        TEXT
        , PADDLE
        , BALL
        , BRICK
    };
public:
    Resource(int resourceID) : _id{resourceID} {}
};
```

In the interest of familiarizing myself with C++11, however, I would like to switch to a scoped enumeration. I'm sure I'm missing something here (the code won't compile, after all!). Faulty revised code is as follows:

```
class Resource {
private:
    ResourceType _id;
protected:
    enum class ResourceType : int {
        TEXT = 0
        , PADDLE
        , BALL
        , BRICK
    };
public:
    Resource(ResourceType resourceID) : _id{resourceID} {}
};
```

Given the compiler error I'm receiving ("error: 'ResourceType' does not name a type" at the line `ResourceType _id;`), it seems that I may need to prototype my enum class elsewhere, but my attempts have been in vain. Please advise!

Comment: That has nothing to do with C++11. The original code was already broken, as it should have said `ResourceType _id` there, too.

Comment: Ah - good catch; compiles, but is in bad form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to declare the type before using it, like so:

```
class Resource {
protected:
    enum class ResourceType : int {
        TEXT = 0
        , PADDLE
        , BALL
        , BRICK
    };
private:
    ResourceType _id;
public:
    Resource(ResourceType resourceID) : _id{ resourceID } {}
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Not sure why I hadn't considered simply moving that block of code instead of trying to use prototypes - kinda silly in retrospect!

Comment: @Nate I think you mean "forward declarations"; "prototypes" is more vague, more _historical_ and not widely used terminology in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're correct - I guess this is what happens when you teach yourself a language via internet resources. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Nate: Yes, it is! :)